# Real-life examples of Generic Methods in .NET and ASP. NET MVC

Tags: .net, generics, methods

Could give me some reasonable real-life examples of 
Generic Methods in .NET for some simple desktop application?

Which the scenarios are there available?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most commonly used generic methods are probably the extension methods in [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) and [`Queryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.aspx), i.e. the ones forming LINQ.

To go back a bit earlier, [`List<T>.ConvertAll<TOutput>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx) is a good example of converting a list of one type (`T`) to another type (`TOutput`). In this case the *type* is generic (the `T` of `List<T>` and the method is *also* generic (in `TOutput`).